# Getting offset from index in binary file

Tags: c#

I'm looking for the value in a binary file, and its location is in the index of the binary file. I'm using the following code, and its not getting me the right bytes back out of the binary file.

```
long offset = 0;

//Open read stream
Stream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
BinaryReader brFile = new BinaryReader(fileStream);

//Read index to find start position
fileStream.Seek(0xC, SeekOrigin.Begin);
byte[] b = brFile.ReadBytes(4);

//Convert to long value
for (int x = 0; x < byErr.Length; x++)
    offset = System.Convert.ToInt64(b[x].ToString()); //I'm assuming this is the problem

//Cleanup
fileStream.Flush();
b = null;

//Read needed value
fileStream.Position = offset;
fileStream.Seek(-0x60, SeekOrigin.Current); //The value I need is 0x60 BEFORE the index location
b = brFile.ReadBytes(4);

//Cleanup
fileStream.Flush();
fileStream.Close();
brFile.Close();
```

I'm getting the correct value from the first read, at `0xC`, but I'm not converting the offset right. I tried converting it to a string first and getting the right string value, but the moment I try to get it to long its searching the wrong area. Also note that the data I need is actually `ox60` BEFORE the index location given to me in the binary.

Comment: please open the file you are reading on a hex editor and paste here the content of the 0xC offset (4 bytes) and what number should it be converted to

Comment: Can you give a ASCI layout of the binary format?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is definitely the problem:

```
for (int x = 0; x < byErr.Length; x++)
{
    offset = System.Convert.ToInt64(b[x].ToString());
}
```

You're converting *each byte* of the index individually to a string, then parsing it and assigning it to `offset`. So only the last byte is actually going to be used.

You can try:

```
long offset = br.ReadInt32();
```

instead of calling `ReadBytes(4)` to start with. If that uses the wrong endianness, you can use my `EndianBinaryReader` class from [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil).

You should log some diagnostic information to show what index you've read, and compare that with what you expect.

I'd also advise you to change your seeking code to:

```
fileStream.Position = offset - 60;
```

for simplicity. Additionally, flushing the file stream you're reading from and setting `b` to null are unnecessary, and you should use a `using` statement for your `FileStream`, at which point you don't need to manually close anything.

Comment: I had a += on there, must have lost it while editing it, though I still know this is my problem. Let me put some values out to try and clarify. At 0xC the next 4 bytes are 00 00 04 A0 which corresponds to location 0x4A0, which is 0x60 AFTER where I need to read the next 4 bytes from (at 0x440). Now I don't need need its int32 or uint32 (which is the -1610350592 and 2684616704 that I'm getting for the offset variable). I need its actual hex value in a long format so I can use it with .Position or .Seek to get the next 4 bytes I need. The actual offset I need is stored in the file as hex.

Comment: @James: Using `+=` won't help on its own. Looks like you want EndianBitConverter or EndianBinaryReader, specifying BigEndian. You *could* do it manually yourself, but you might as well use an existing library...

Answer (score 0):

Well I found this using google, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ab831d92-14ad-437e-9b03-102d90f44d22/ and got it to work for what I needed. I'm converting from byte to string to long, so it seems like its definitely not the most efficient way, but it works perfectly. I also realized that .Position and .Seek were asking for a decimal value when I was trying to give it a hex offset.

```
    public static string HexStr(byte[] p)
    {
        char[] c = new char[p.Length * 2 + 2];
        byte b;
        c[0] = '0'; c[1] = 'x';
        for (int y = 0, x = 2; y < p.Length; ++y, ++x)
        {
            b = ((byte)(p[y] >> 4));
            c[x] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30);
            b = ((byte)(p[y] & 0xF));
            c[++x] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30);
        }
        return new string(c);
    }
```

So now MY code looks like this....

```
        using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            BinaryReader brFile = new BinaryReader(fileStream);

            //Read index to find start position
            fileStream.Position = 0xC;
            byte[] offsetByte = brFile.ReadBytes(4);
            string offsetString = HexStr(offsetByte);
            long offset = System.Convert.ToInt64(offsetString, 16);

            //Read needed value
            fileStream.Position = offset - 96; //-0x60 translates to -96
            byte[] byVal = brFile.ReadBytes(4);
        }
```